# running ant to install netbeans on mac : Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I am trying to install [NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/nb110.html).

As you can see if you click on the link, I had to install ant first. So I went [there](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#getBinary), downloaded the zip file an uncompressed it in `/Users/myname/` and added this to my `./bash_profile`:

```
export ANT_HOME=/Users/⁨myname/ant
export PATH=$PATH:usr/local/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

I couldn't make ant work so I finally ended up installing it using HomeBrew: `brew install ant`.

From there I had access to the ant command line.

Then I downloaded the binaries of NetBeans, uncompressed it in `/Users/myname/` and cd into it to run `ant` as requested in the netbeans installation instructions.

But I get the following error:

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

How can I solve this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to mix things up. If you just want to use NetBeans you only need to download the binaries, extract the archive and start NetBeans via [netbeans]/bin/netbeans.sh

You need Ant only if you want to compile NetBeans from the sources. In this case make sure Ant is available in version >= 1.10 and you downloaded and extracted the source archive. The binaries archive is not needed.

Comment: I see; I was indeed mixing up source and binaries. Thank you very much for your help !